# loading a jsp page contains Gmap , on div in another jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load a jsp page which consist google map , inside another jsp page div but its not showing map on that div. Other two jsp pages processed , unprocessed coming on divs fine.

//  JSP hello.jsp

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
$("#map_canvas").load("map.jsp");
$("#tabs-1").load("Processed.jsp");
$("#tabs-2").load("UnProcessed.jsp");
});
</script>

<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li> <a href="#map_canvas">GMaps</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#tabs-1">Processed </a></li>
    <li> <a href="#tabs-2">UnProcessed </a></li>
</ul>
<div id ="map_canvas"></div>
<div id="tabs-1"></div>
<div id="tabs-2"></div>
</div></body></html>
```

// map.jsp

```
<head>
<title>Simple Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  #map-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 8,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>

// I had already spent too much time on this but still not getting result , map is not   loading on page , please help me to load map.jsp on`map_canvas` div in hello.jsp . Thanks A tonn...
```

Comment: can you please tell me what happens, when you open the main.jsp directly, like http://localhost/../map.jsp

Comment: when i am calling map.jsp directly map is loading fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dude, i got your issue,

In map.jsp, use may be using some style like

```
#map-canvas {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
```

remove and paste this css in the  hello.jsp code and 
try pasting the javascript code in hello.jsp page, ie initialize and loadScript function
rest every thing works nice, have tested locally here, should work for you also

Comment: Thanks for quick reply SAM , but still not getting map. :(

Comment: try pasting the javascript code in hello.jsp page, ie initialize and loadScript function

Comment: Thanks alot SAM , by putting js code in that same jsp , now its working...  :)